# Python 3 AttributeError: Module 'sys' Has No Attribute 'argv'

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

As I am going through an example in a book:

```
#! python3
# pw.py password locker program

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7min18DDuvMJuxESSLHFhTxFtjvB6',
             'blog': 'VmALQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
             'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.agrv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python3 pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + 'copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

Running this program returns an attributeError:

```
kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/py$ python3 pw.py email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kingvon/Desktop/py/pw.py", line 9, in <module>
    if len(sys.agrv) < 2:
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'agrv'
```

Why is this? I feel this is a compatibility issue as this book uses Windows. I'm using latest Kali Linux.

Comment: You have a typo mate, you wrote `agrv` instead of `argv`.

Comment: It should be ```sys.argv``` not ```sys.agrv```

Comment: Hahahahaha what a joke, took me a whole question to spot that typo!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.
Instead of this line

`if len(sys.agrv) < 2:`

Write this line:

`if len(sys.argv) < 2:`